# Svelte app showing blank page in Docker container on local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, svelte

I'm trying to containerise a Svelte App, it runs fine outside the container, however, after I build and run the Docker container I see a blank page, I do see the title of the app the page though is totally blank.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15.4 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: aren't you missing a build step ?

Comment: You're right! I added 'RUN npm run build' after 'RUN npm install' and I' still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
FROM node:15.4 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```